# Replace STYLE content javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

I have a JavaScript variable:

```
var s =   
 "<html><head><style>body{a:b;c:d}</style></head><body></body></html>";
```

First, I am extracting the content inside `<style>` tags:

```
s = s.split(/(<style[^>]*>|<\/style>)/i)[2]; 

// s == "body{a:b;c:d}";
```

Then I am doing something with `s` and after the manipulation I need to append it on `<style>` tags.

How can I insert `s` between `<style>` and `</style>` ?

Example: Modified var s = "body{x:h;f:l;}";

so I need the resulting content like this:

```
 "<html><head><style>body{x:h;f:l;}</style></head><body></body></html>";
```

**Update**: jQuery is allowed - But only string manipulation is
   allowed. Pure JavaScript solutions have first priority.

Comment: If you are allowed to use jQuery the answer to this would be much simpler. Please indicate that.

Comment: jQuery is allowed ,But a neat Javascript solution goes priority.Also i cant convert this to DOM.

Comment: cool, then yeah the regex solution below seems like the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var s  = "<html><head><style>body{a:b;c:d}</style></head><body></body></html>";
var b = s.split(/(<style[^>]*>|<\/style>)/i)[2]; 
s = s.replace(b,"body{x:h;f:l;}");
```

finally, s is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
var s  ="body{a:b;c:d}";
    var newS = s.replace("body{a:b;c:d}", "body{x:h;f:l;}");
    alert(s);
    alert(newS);
```

Comment: Please take a look at the Question : this is the one that i want to append,please tell me how can i append the news to style tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use below mentioned code

```
var someHTML = "<html><head><style>body{a:b;c:d}</style></head><body></body></html>";
var styleContents = someHTML.split(/(<style[^>]*>|<\/style>)/i)[2];
document.getElementById('style').innerHTML = styleContents;
```

Comment: Sorry,i cant convert to DOM.Last line makes problems,i cant access like `document.getElementById('style').innerHTML` ,because all thease are strings.